# Chassidish pronunciation: הוא and היא

Tags: tefilla, pronunciation, chasidut-hasidism

In Chassidishe pronunciation, I am under the impression that the וּ makes a "i" sound, correct? If this is so, do they differentiate between הוא and היא in davening? How? Seems like it would sound the same.

Comment: Not all Chassidim pronounce it this way. I've heard this pronunciation among Stamar and Vishnitz. I'm sure there are others. From what I could tell, the "oo" sound is pronounced somewhere between "oo" and "ay". It seems to have a slight diphthong starting as "oo" with a slide to "ay". The "ee" sound is "ee". It is hard to notice to the untrained ear, but there is a difference from what I can tell. There is a Satmar man whom I see in my shul, frequently. I'll ask him, B"N, next time I see him.

Comment: @DanF - B''H thank you. Please ask him for me. I'm very curious with the Chassidish Hebrew.

Comment: It's possible that they don't differentiate, just as those who pronounce *patach* and *kamatz* [*gadol*] identically therefore don't differentiate, via pronunciation, between "יָם" ("sea") and "יַם" ("sea of"), for example.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Or perhaps more strikingly: "אדנָי" (God) and "אדנַי" (my masters)

Comment: Is your question whether they fulfill their obligation in prayer, or simply what they do? If the former, then consider clarifying that. If the latter, then this does seem to be on topic any more than "which language do most Hassidic programmers use" both ask about people (presumably Jews), but not about Judaism itself.

Comment: @mevaqesh - It's not about Hasidim. It's about Hebrew pronunciation within a certain sect of Judaism. There are many other questions on this S''E dealing with Hebrew pronunciation, be it Ashkenazi, Sefardi, etc.

Comment: Not only that, but they are both spelt as הוא in the Humash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most American and European *Chassidim* use what is often (wrongly) called *Chassidish* pronunciation. However, *Hungarian* is probably a more precise term, as even non-*Chassidim* that stem from parts of Austria, Hungary, and southern Germany use this pronunciation.

A large majority do not distinguish between וּ and י ִ, pronouncing both [/i/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel) as in English *fl**ee**ce*, French *f**i**n**i***, and German *Z**ie**l*. However a minority pronounce the former [/y/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_rounded_vowel) as in French *cr**u***, German *sch**ü**tzen*, and Scandinavian *s**y**n*.

**Source:** Myself and everyone around me...

Comment: Hungarian pronunciation is also thought of as Galitzianer pronunciation, as it is thought to originate there. AFAIK, Oberlander Hungarians don't use this style.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt True, but Unterlanders do.

Comment: @Adám - Boruch Hashem, todah rabbah and yashar koach to you! One question though...how do you pronounce the shuruk/melupim?

Comment: @EzraHoerster You mean me personally? I started off with [/u/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_back_rounded_vowel), switched to /i/, and eventually settled on /y/. Well, at least I try during davening. When speaking Yiddish, I just stick to /i/, despite confusing homonyms like אין and און.